# Access previous versions of Terraform state on Artifactory (remote backend type)?

Tags: terraform, artifactory, terraform-remote-state

Using a `backend "remote"`, it's easily possible store and use Artifactory for the Terraform state. It also does a nice job of versioning.

In case of issues, how would I actually use the previous versions? `terraform state pull` and the like don't allow to specify the name of a specific state file.

So, suppose there are those files:

[image: Screenshot of Artifactory showing various Terraform state file versions]

How would I use `state.1708332113711.json`?

The contents of a state file are encrypted online. I don't know how to decrypt. Content:

```json
{
    "data": {
        "type": "state-versions",
        "attributes": {
            "serial": 7,
            "force": false,
            "md5": "d95c64fc66f9d572a0d5f1256778b56b",
            "lineage": "fd53f4b8-6e4b-1765-2c31-f838c2904a3b",
            "state": "0w1QtQFa45HJ6ocUMKuXvjjyNQ9…uOabYjiHnkRiyDTwSE=",
            "json-state-outputs": "e30="
        },
        "relationships": null
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess delete the two newer ones?

Comment: That wouldn't do it. Without some special configuration (which I know nothing about), only "state.latest.json" is accessible. Sure, I could copy the file to theere, but that would destroy it. To only "look into it", that's no good. The content is encrypted, so downloading and "cat" doesn't do it either.